# How to update the navigation database on a Garmin GPS 165 TSO?

Tags: gnss, ifr-navigation

What is the update process for updating GPS 165 TSO. The updates are available on shop.jeppesen however, how to transfer them to this GPS ??

Answer (score 3):

If you check out Jeppesen's support pages, it will point you to the [Jeppesen Distribution Manager (JDM) software](https://support.jeppesen.com/article?aid=kA2600000004FtOCAU), available for Windows, MacOS, and iPad/iPhone. You need to download and install the software.

On the page for the specific version of the JDM, there is a section near the bottom labeled Documentation. Follow the link for "Required Hardware for Updating Databases."

In that document, you can find for the the Garmin 165 you need the [SkyBound G2 USB Adapter](https://shop.jeppesen.com/All-Products/Pilot-Supplies/Navigation-Equipment-Hardware/NavData-Hardware/Skybound-G2-USB-Adapter/p/10533225) and a [Blank NavData Card](https://shop.jeppesen.com/All-Products/Pilot-Supplies/Navigation-Equipment-Hardware/NavData-Hardware/Blank-NavData-Card-for-Garmin-155-155XL,-165,-300-300XL/p/10353678).

The JDM will allow you to download the database to your computer. The USB adapter allows you to transfer it to the NavData card which you can install in the unit. You'll want 2 cards as you'll want to download the next cycle before the current cycle expires. You can then just switch cards on the appropriate day.